# List of active ports and app names in bokeh and nginx

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, bokeh

I am running different bokeh apps on different ports on my virtual machine using nginx. For example:

```
bokeh serve app1 --address 127.0.0.1 --port 5001 
bokeh serve app2 --address 127.0.0.1 --port 5002
```

The nginx is configured so the each app corresponds to a different location. For example:

```
server {
    location app1 {
    proxy-pass https://localhost:5001/app1;
    ....
    }
    location app2 {
    proxy-pass https://localhost:5002/app2;
    ....
    }
}
```

How can I list out all ports and app locations?

Expected result:

```
> app1 runs on port 5000
> app2 runs on port 5001
```

I have tried `netstat -tulpn | grep '127.0.0.1'` but from that I can retrieve only the active ports and not the name of the app.

Why I need this? My apps are invoked automatically and run on predefined range of ports. I would like to monitor at each time which app is running on which port.

**----- UPDATE**

I manage to get the desired output, using:

```
ps -ef | grep "bokeh serve" | awk '$8~"python" {print $15 "  " $11}'
```

but isn't there a nicer way?  (like a bokeh serve monitor?)

Answer (score 0):

do you consider using `supervisord` ? as daemon management? to running your app...
then you can code using http://supervisord.org/api.html

for get the status...

Comment: Hi, @gumelargum thanks for the reply, however, I don't see how `supervisord` could help to produce the expected result (bokeh app name : port). I need to call the bokeh server in order for it to work together with `nginx`. If you can show an example code, I could accept your answer.